# The mysterious list

Tags: lateral-thinking, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

I was at my friends house and he has this list on his fridge that didn't seem to make any sense to me. I am certain it has a meaning since my friend is not one for frivolous things. Also his memory is not the greatest, so this list is probably there to help him remember something. Here is the list:

> Ice:
>
> Nottingham
> Obi Wan x2
> Mater
> Benign Growth x3
> Aidan Turner x2
> Wanda Maximoff
> "The end is nigh, nerd" x3
> Wonder Woman x2
> "Unseen eye knows"
> Alex Evans
> Tuuka Rask
> Leaf Ivory
> Bandwith reducer

Do you guys have any idea what this list is supposed to be/help remind my friend of?

**Note:**

- Don't think too much about the knowledge tag, it basically means you
  might have to google a thing or two on your way to the answer
- The "x2","x3",etc.. means it was listed that many times on the list, I shortened it so it fit better here. Not having a xN means 1 time

**Hint:**

> Whenever I see my friend look at the list he hums to himself, sounds a little like a song or maybe a jingle of some sort

Comment: Is the order of the list important? Specifically, when there's a x2 does that mean the item appears twice in a row?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is:

> The phone number of the New Emergency Services
>  This number is: **0118 999 881 999 119 7253**
>  see also: http://theitcrowd.wikia.com/wiki/New_Emergency_Services

It seems that when spoken,

> Many items in the list have a number hidden within.

So:

> *Not*tingham (naught) → **0**
>  Obi *Wan* x2 (one) → **1 1**
>  M*ate*r (eight) → **8**
>  Be*nign* Growth x3 → **9 9 9**
>  *Aid*an Turner x2 (eight) → **8 8**
>  *Wan*da Maximoff (one) → **1**
>  "The end is *nigh, n*erd" x3 → **9 9 9**
>  *Won*der Woman x2 (one) → **1 1**
>  "Unsee*n eye kn*ows" (nine) → **9**
>  Ale*x Evan*s (seven) → **7**
>  *Tuu*ka Rask (two) → **2**
>  Lea*f Iv*ory (five) → **5**
>  Bandwi*th re*ducer (three) → **3**

Comment: i think is also worth to mention, the list starts from word ice, which is also acronym for "In Case of Emergency".

Comment: Hah! Thanks, @Gamow. Should've just googled my list of numbers, it appears.

Comment: This is correct! The video for it has a jingle to remember it by which is where the hint comes from

Comment: This tune is going to be stuck in my head for a while... I just watched the video and it was hilarious!

Comment: Dangit, second time this site has put that tune in my head.  First time was when I brought it up in response to a HELP/emergency number riddle. :P

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the connections between these items are, but here's a list of what they mean.

Nottingham

> Nottingham is the main city in Robin Hood.

Obi Wan

> Obi Wan is of course, a Star Wars character.

Mater

> Mater, I assume is from that Pixar movie *cars*.

Benign growth

> Benign growth is a term for a *tumor*.

Aidan Turner

> Aidan Turner is an actor

Wanda Maximoff

> Wanda Maximoff is the identity of *Scarlet Witch* from Marvel's comics.

"The end is nigh, nerd" x3

> No idea what the next line means.

Wonder Woman

> Wonder Woman is obvious

"Unseen eye knows"

> No idea about that next line.

Alex Evans

> Alex Evans is a model.

Tuukka Rask

> Tuukka Rask is an ice hockey player.

Leaf-Ivory

> Leaf-Ivory could refer to a type of paper.

bandwidth reducer

> And a bandwidth reducer is a piece of electronic equipment.

---

I hope this helps!

Comment: Added spoilers, The unseen eye ==> The book: The All-Seeing Unseen Eye of God and Other Sermons?

Comment: That's what I thought, too, but it seemed a stretch to me.